STM32F103 no startup file in IAR Embedded Workbench
STM32F103, Hello I want to use Interrupt on GPIO peripheral, I am using IAR Embedded Workbrench tool for programming.
But IAR don't create startup file and it is necessary as I see. How can I import startup file inside IAR project?

You'd be better using STM32CubeIDE to get started. It can create you a fully functional skeleton project for your MCU. Your question as stated is far too vague to be answered on StackOverflow.

It is better for you to use STM32CubeMX to build a template project for IAR workbench.
If you still try to fix your project errors in IAR (i.e. startup file errors) better to see this link from IAR site
https://www.iar.com/knowledge/support/technical-notes/debugger/application-does-not-run-stand-alone/
You can add a startup file based on you microcontroller to your project tree
